# Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '72x72' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions < 7.0

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, application-loader

I'm running into an issue delivering my app using Adobe's PhoneGapBuild. I'm getting an error in Application Loader that prevents me from proceeding.

"ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '72x72' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions < 7.0."

I've noted other similar postings to try an eliminate the issue but it still persists. I've triple checked and rewritten my config.xml, verified the file is pathed properly, renamed the file to the exact file name used in the PhoneGap documentation, verified the file dimensions and recreated the file from scratch.

Nothing I've done so far is getting rid of this error.

Here's a screen grab of the "res/icons/ios/" directory.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeLSB.png)

Here's what my config.xml is for the ios icons:

```
<platform name="ios">
<!-- iOS 8.0+ -->
<!-- iPhone 6 Plus  -->
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180" />

<!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
<!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
<!-- iPad -->
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
<!-- iOS 6.1 -->
<!-- Spotlight Icon -->
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
<!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
<!-- iPad -->
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
<!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
<!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100" />

<!-- images are determined by width and height. The following are supported -->
<splash src="res/splash/ios/splash-iphone.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480"/>
<splash src="res/splash/ios/splash-2x-iphone.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960"/>
<splash src="res/splash/ios/splash-portrait-ipad.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024"/>
<splash src="res/splash/ios/splash-portrait-2x-ipad.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048"/>
<splash src="res/splash/ios/splash-landscape-ipad.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768"/>
<splash src="res/splash/ios/splash-landscape-2x-ipad.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536"/>
<splash src="res/splash/ios/splash-568h-2x-iphone.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136"/>
<splash src="res/splash/ios/splash-667h.png" gap:platform="ios" width="750" height="1334"/>
<splash src="res/splash/ios/splash-736h.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1242" height="2208"/>
<splash src="res/splash/ios/splash-landscape-736h.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2208" height="1242"/>
</platform>
```

Comment: Rob do you zip your www folder and then use build.phonegap to generate the .apk file for the application loader?

Comment: Yes, I compress the project folder into a .zip file then upload to PGB for generate the .ipa, .apk and .xap.

Comment: The config.xml that you are revising, is it located in your www folder? that's where it should be with the relevant revisions.

Comment: Yes, the config.xml is at the root level of the project directory.

Comment: just to clarify, config.xml and www and res are all in the same root level. /res does not should be in the /www ,nor config.xml inside the /www!